# Angular 6 Universal with firebase cloud functions

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm newbie to angular universal with firebase cloud functions.

I've tried to do the angular universal and deploy to firebase with using cloud functions. And everything(Node.js server, firebase serve) are work correctly but when I deploy(hosting & functions) to firebase, I got this error in firebase cloud functions.

```
ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of undefined
    at resolveNgModuleDep (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8160:34)
    at _createClass (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8229:36)
    at _createProviderInstance (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8193:30)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8156:25)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8864:20)
    at resolveDep (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9229:49)
    at createClass (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9109:36)
    at createDirectiveInstance (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8986:24)
    at createViewNodes (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10206:40)
    at createRootView (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10120:9)
    at resolvePromise (/user_code/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:814:31)
    at resolvePromise (/user_code/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:771:17)
    at /user_code/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:873:17
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/user_code/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:421:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3804:37)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/user_code/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:420:36)
    at Zone.runTask (/user_code/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:188:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (/user_code/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:595:35)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (/user_code/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:500:21)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (/user_code/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:485:48)
  rejection: 
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of undefined
       at resolveNgModuleDep (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8160:34)
       at _createClass (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8229:36)
       at _createProviderInstance (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8193:30)
       at resolveNgModuleDep (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8156:25)
       at NgModuleRef_.get (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8864:20)
       at resolveDep (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9229:49)
       at createClass (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9109:36)
       at createDirectiveInstance (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8986:24)
       at createViewNodes (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10206:40)
       at createRootView (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10120:9),
  promise: 
   ZoneAwarePromise {
     __zone_symbol__state: 0,
     __zone_symbol__value: 
      TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of undefined
          at resolveNgModuleDep (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8160:34)
          at _createClass (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8229:36)
          at _createProviderInstance (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8193:30)
          at resolveNgModuleDep (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8156:25)
          at NgModuleRef_.get (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8864:20)
          at resolveDep (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9229:49)
          at createClass (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9109:36)
          at createDirectiveInstance (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8986:24)
          at createViewNodes (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10206:40)
          at createRootView (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10120:9) },
  zone: 
   Zone {
     _properties: { isAngularZone: true },
     _parent: 
      Zone {
        _properties: {},
        _parent: null,
        _name: '<root>',
        _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
     _name: 'angular',
     _zoneDelegate: 
      ZoneDelegate {
        _taskCounts: [Object],
        zone: [Circular],
        _parentDelegate: [Object],
        _forkZS: null,
        _forkDlgt: null,
        _forkCurrZone: [Object],
        _interceptZS: null,
        _interceptDlgt: null,
        _interceptCurrZone: [Object],
        _invokeZS: [Object],
        _invokeDlgt: [Object],
        _invokeCurrZone: [Circular],
        _handleErrorZS: [Object],
        _handleErrorDlgt: [Object],
        _handleErrorCurrZone: [Circular],
        _scheduleTaskZS: [Object],
        _scheduleTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _scheduleTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
        _invokeTaskZS: [Object],
        _invoke
```

I've tried to re-install `node_modules` but still got this error in cloud functions. How could I fix this error? Please help.

This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "webpack:prerender": "webpack --config webpack.prerender.config.js",
    "build:prerender": "node dist/browser/prerender.js",
    "serve:prerender": "http-server dist/browser -o",
    "build:all": "ng build --prod && ng run myproject:server && npm run webpack:prerender && npm run build:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^6.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.0",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "ws": "^6.0.0",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0"
  }
}
```

server.ts

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

// DOM libs required for Firebase
(global as any).WebSocket = require('ws');
(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import { join } from 'path';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
const APP_NAME = 'browser';

const {
  AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  LAZY_MODULE_MAP
} = require(`./dist/server/main`);

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

// Set the engine
app.engine(
  'html',
  ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)]
  })
);

app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('/**/*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, APP_NAME, 'index'), {
    req,
    res
  });
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, APP_NAME));

// Static Assets
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, APP_NAME)));

// Point all routes to Universal
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start Express Server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

webpack.prerender.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const APP_NAME = 'browser';

module.exports = {
  entry: {  prerender: './server.ts' },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, `dist/${APP_NAME}`),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
}
```

This is `functions/index.js`

```
require('zone.js/dist/zone-node');

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const { enableProdMode } = require('@angular/core');
const { renderModuleFactory } = require('@angular/platform-server');
const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');

const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');

enableProdMode();

const index = require('fs')
  .readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/browser/index.html'), 'utf8')
  .toString();

let app = express();

app.get('**', function(req, res) {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    url: req.path,
    document: index,
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }).then(html => res.status(200).send(html));
});

exports.universal = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Functions and hosting are two very different firebase features. What is your issue : a function doesn't work, or your project isn't deployed ?

Comment: I already deployed to firebase but a function doesn't work and get the error "Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of undefined".

Comment: This error happens in development mode, it certainly doesn't pop up in your website's console (or you did something very wrong). So if you have this error in developement mode, how did you build your application to deploy it ?

Comment: I do not have this error in development mode. My application could run correctly but when I build application, I got 4 warnings (eg. WARNING in ./node_modules/ws/lib/buffer-util.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bufferutil'). I don't know if these warning are related to error in cloud function.

Comment: So where can you see this error excatly ?

Comment: In firebase cloud function log.

Comment: And when you build the project in local mode, you don't have any error, just warnings ?

Comment: Yes. I get only just warnings.

Comment: Then consider opening an issue on firebase's repository

Comment: OK I will. Thank you for your reply :)